# Why do I keep getting Controller method not found on Laravel Confide creating user

Tags: php, methods, controller, laravel, laravel-4

Right I have set up confide user authentication on my Laravel site.

I have ran everything as exactly as they said on the github page. When I direct myself to the user/create page I am presented with the form that I would normally posy me new info into. When I press submit I get this error on this url: /user.

On inspection these are the errors I get:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.

```
 * Handle calls to missing methods on the controller.
     *
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function missingMethod($parameters)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Controller method not found.");
    }

15. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Routing/­Controllers/­Controller.php290
14. Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller missingMethod
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Routing/­Controllers/­Controller.php302
13. Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller __call
…/­app/­controllers/­UserController.php42
12. User save
…/­app/­controllers/­UserController.php42
11. UserController store
<#unknown>0
```

My UserController.php is setup like so:

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Confide Controller Template
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the default Confide controller template for controlling user
| authentication. Feel free to change to your needs.
|
*/

class UserController extends BaseController {


    /**
     * Displays the form for account creation
     *
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make(Config::get('confide::signup_form'));
    }

    /**
     * Stores new account
     *
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $user = new User;

        $user->username = Input::get( 'username' );
        $user->email = Input::get( 'email' );
        $user->password = Input::get( 'password' );

        // The password confirmation will be removed from model
        // before saving. This field will be used in Ardent's
        // auto validation.
        $user->password_confirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );

        // Save if valid. Password field will be hashed before save
        $user->save();

        if ( $user->id )
        {
            // Redirect with success message, You may replace "Lang::get(..." for your custom message.
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                            ->with( 'notice', Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.account_created') );
        }
        else
        {
            // Get validation errors (see Ardent package)
            $error = $user->errors()->all(':message');

                        return Redirect::action('UserController@create')
                            ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with( 'error', $error );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the login form
     *
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if( Confide::user() )
        {
            // If user is logged, redirect to internal 
            // page, change it to '/admin', '/dashboard' or something
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        }
        else
        {
            return View::make(Config::get('confide::login_form'));
        }
    }

    public function do_login()
    {
        $input = array(
            'email'    => Input::get( 'email' ), // May be the username too
            'username' => Input::get( 'email' ), // so we have to pass both
            'password' => Input::get( 'password' ),
            'remember' => Input::get( 'remember' ),
        );

        // If you wish to only allow login from confirmed users, call logAttempt
        // with the second parameter as true.
        // logAttempt will check if the 'email' perhaps is the username.
        // Get the value from the config file instead of changing the controller
        if ( Confide::logAttempt( $input, Config::get('confide::signup_confirm') ) ) 
        {
            // Redirect the user to the URL they were trying to access before
            // caught by the authentication filter IE Redirect::guest('user/login').
            // Otherwise fallback to '/'
            // Fix pull #145
            return Redirect::intended('/'); // change it to '/admin', '/dashboard' or something
        }
        else
        {
            $user = new User;

            // Check if there was too many login attempts
            if( Confide::isThrottled( $input ) )
            {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.too_many_attempts');
            }
            elseif( $user->checkUserExists( $input ) and ! $user->isConfirmed( $input ) )
            {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.not_confirmed');
            }
            else
            {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_credentials');
            }

                        return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                            ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with( 'error', $err_msg );
        }
    }

    public function confirm( $code )
    {
        if ( Confide::confirm( $code ) )
        {
            $notice_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.confirmation');
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                            ->with( 'notice', $notice_msg );
        }
        else
        {
            $error_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_confirmation');
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                            ->with( 'error', $error_msg );
        }
    }

    public function forgot_password()
    {
        return View::make(Config::get('confide::forgot_password_form'));
    }

    public function do_forgot_password()
    {
        if( Confide::forgotPassword( Input::get( 'email' ) ) )
        {
            $notice_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.password_forgot');
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                            ->with( 'notice', $notice_msg );
        }
        else
        {
            $error_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_password_forgot');
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@forgot_password')
                            ->withInput()
                ->with( 'error', $error_msg );
        }
    }

    public function reset_password( $token )
    {
        return View::make(Config::get('confide::reset_password_form'))
                ->with('token', $token);
    }


    public function do_reset_password()
    {
        $input = array(
            'token'=>Input::get( 'token' ),
            'password'=>Input::get( 'password' ),
            'password_confirmation'=>Input::get( 'password_confirmation' ),
        );

        // By passing an array with the token, password and confirmation
        if( Confide::resetPassword( $input ) )
        {
            $notice_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.password_reset');
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                            ->with( 'notice', $notice_msg );
        }
        else
        {
            $error_msg = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_password_reset');
                        return Redirect::action('UserController@reset_password', array('token'=>$input['token']))
                            ->withInput()
                ->with( 'error', $error_msg );
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Confide::logout();

        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

This is what the php artisan confide:controller creates for you and then you can do the same for routes which outputs this in the routes.php file for you:

```
// Confide routes
Route::get( 'user/create',                 'UserController@create');
Route::post('user',                        'UserController@store');
Route::get( 'user/login',                  'UserController@login');
Route::post('user/login',                  'UserController@do_login');
Route::get( 'user/confirm/{code}',         'UserController@confirm');
Route::get( 'user/forgot_password',        'UserController@forgot_password');
Route::post('user/forgot_password',        'UserController@do_forgot_password');
Route::get( 'user/reset_password/{token}', 'UserController@reset_password');
Route::post('user/reset_password',         'UserController@do_reset_password');
Route::get( 'user/logout',                 'UserController@logout');
```

In my User.php model I have this setup which is normal:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends ConfideUser {
         use HasRole;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'users';

    public function getPresenter()
    {
        return new UserPresenter($this);
    }

    /**
     * Get user by username
     * @param $username
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserByUsername( $username )
    {
        return $this->where('username', '=', $username)->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get the date the user was created.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function joined()
    {
        return String::date(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-n-j G:i:s', $this->created_at));
    }

    /**
     * Save roles inputted from multiselect
     * @param $inputRoles
     */
    public function saveRoles($inputRoles)
    {
        if(! empty($inputRoles)) {
            $this->roles()->sync($inputRoles);
        } else {
            $this->roles()->detach();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns user's current role ids only.
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function currentRoleIds()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roleIds = false;
        if( !empty( $roles ) ) {
            $roleIds = array();
            foreach( $roles as &$role )
            {
                $roleIds[] = $role->id;
            }
        }
        return $roleIds;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect after auth.
     * If ifValid is set to true it will redirect a logged in user.
     * @param $redirect
     * @param bool $ifValid
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function checkAuthAndRedirect($redirect, $ifValid=false)
    {
        // Get the user information
        $user = Auth::user();
        $redirectTo = false;

        if(empty($user->id) && ! $ifValid) // Not logged in redirect, set session.
        {
            Session::put('loginRedirect', $redirect);
            $redirectTo = Redirect::to('user/login')
                ->with( 'notice', Lang::get('user/user.login_first') );
        }
        elseif(!empty($user->id) && $ifValid) // Valid user, we want to redirect.
        {
            $redirectTo = Redirect::to($redirect);
        }

        return array($user, $redirectTo);
    }

    public function currentUser()
    {
        return (new Confide(new ConfideEloquentRepository()))->user();
    }

}
```

So from this I can go to the form on /user/create and it outputs the form which means that route is working but on submit I get the No method error.

Can anyone shed some light onto this please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant routes also? edit: Nevermind just realized I overlooked it.

Comment: Where is the form posting to?

Comment: I cannot figure out the error from whats posted above but here are my guesses. The form is not posting to the correct route.

Also instead of using login() and do_login() you should probably try  using Laravel's built in restful controllers. You just need to define a route once using `Route::controller('users', 'UserController');` and then after that all you can define a get and post for whatever you want. users/login route will call UsersController@getLogin() posting to users/pizza will call UsersController@postPizza() ect ect...

Comment: its saying it cannot find the controller method at all which is bizarre

Comment: @M Where is the form posting? It might be calling post on a controller method that doesn't exist?

Comment: its posting to http://localhost:8000/user which should work. I am not sure if its to do with namespaces and defining the User model?

Comment: Try typing `composer dump-autoload` into your terminal from your project root. See if the form posts correctly now.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you don't mind my suggestion, I'd spend a few hours learning about composer autoloading. Its a super powerful tool and understanding whats going on will make understanding laravel so much easier. Feel free to message me if you have a specific question on it. [Reference](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Comment: Thanks alot echochamber, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you type composer-dump autoload, composer recreates a bunch of files which tell it what classes should be registered into the autoloader. classmap autoloading requires you to composer dump-autoload whenever you make new files in a directory being autoloaded. psr-0 autoloading requires you to namespace your files but from then on you don't need to composer dump-autoload except for the first time you define the psr-0 autoloading in your composer.json file.